# git add remote branch

Tags: git

I want to add a remote, and a branch of that remote.

I did `git remote add <newname> <url>`, then I did `git fetch --all` but `git branch -a` is not showing any branch of the remote. My .git/config is showing the added remote.

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: What happens when you `git fetch remote branch:branch && git co branch`?

Answer (score 339):

I am not sure if you are trying to create a remote branch from a local branch or vice versa, so I've outlined both scenarios as well as provided information on merging the remote and local branches.

Creating a remote called "github":

```
git remote add github git://github.com/jdoe/coolapp.git
git fetch github
```

List all remote branches:

```
git branch -r
  github/gh-pages
  github/master
  github/next
  github/pu
```

**Create a new local branch (test) from a github's remote branch (pu):**

```
git branch test github/pu
git checkout test
```

**Merge changes from github's remote branch (pu) with local branch (test):**

```
git fetch github
git checkout test
git merge github/pu
```

**Update github's remote branch (pu) from a local branch (test):**

```
git push github test:pu
```

Creating a new branch on a remote uses the same syntax as updating a remote branch.  For example, create new remote branch (beta) on github from local branch (test):

```
git push github test:beta
```

Delete remote branch (pu) from github:

```
git push github :pu
```

Comment: Is there a way to create the local branch without specifying the name, such that it automagically takes the same name as the remote branch?

Comment: @Dubslow `git checkout --track github/pu`, see [here](https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches)

Comment: Great answer but "github" is an unnecessarily confusing name for this repo. example_repo or almost anything else would be less confusing.

Answer (score 32):

You can check if you got your remote setup right and have the proper permissions with

```
git ls-remote origin
```

if you called your remote "origin". If you get an error you probably don't have your security set up correctly such as uploading your public key to github for example. If things are setup correctly, you will get a list of the remote references. Now

```
git fetch origin
```

will work barring any other issues like an unplugged network cable.

Once you have that done, you can get any branch you want that the above command listed with

```
git checkout some-branch
```

this will create a local branch of the same name as the remote branch and check it out.

Answer (score 16):

I tested what @Samy Dindane suggested in the comment on the OP.

I believe it works, try

```
git fetch <remote_name> <remote_branch>:<local_branch>
git checkout <local_branch>
```

Here's an example for a fictitious remote repository named `foo` with a branch named `bar` where I create a local branch `bar` tracking the remote:

```
git fetch foo bar:bar
git checkout bar
```

Comment: That is the way you can add remote branch if you cloned your repo with shallow depth

Answer (score 8):

You can probably just do..

```
git checkout branch_name
```

If the remote branch exists on origin then git will track it if it has the same name.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the complete process to create a local repo and push the changes to new remote branch

1. ***Creating local repository:-***

   Initially user may have created the local git repository.

   `$ git init` :- This will make the local folder as Git repository,
2. ***Link the remote branch***:-

   Now challenge is   associate the local git repository with remote **master** branch.

   `$ git remote add RepoName RepoURL`

   usage: git remote add []
3. ***Test the Remote***

   `$ git remote show`   --->Display the remote name

   `$ git remote -v`     --->Display the remote branches
4. ***Now Push to remote***

   `$git add .`   ----> Add all the files and folder as git staged'

   `$git commit -m "Your Commit Message"`  - - - >Commit the message

   `$git push`  - - - - >Push the changes to the upstream

Comment: These are just the instructions for the general case of using git. I don't see anything in this answer specific to the question being asked.

Answer (score 5):

If you  created a local branch named A
and you have a remote branch named B
and you want remote branch B to track the changes of local branch A

do the following on your command line or terminal

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/B A
```

This will setup upstream of your local branch A
to remote branch B

then run

```
git pull
```

to pull the changes from B

then run

```
git push
```

to push the changes to B

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I used the following commands to make it work

```
git fetch origin
git remote add <your_branch> <your_url>
git checkout <your_branch>
```